# Exception:invalid scm URL, on running mvn scm:checkout command.

Tags: cvs, maven, maven-scm

Contents of POM.xml are :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <!-- Parent pom relation
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
    <artifactId>atom</artifactId>
    <version>3.0+</version>
  </parent>
  -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
  <artifactId>cim</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>3.0+</version>
  <name>cim transformation</name>
  **<scm>
    <connection>scm:cvs:pserver:change1t@aukjupcx:/home/cvs/cvsroot</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:cvs:pserver:change1t@aukjupcx:/home/cvs/cvsroot</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:cvs:pserver:change1t@aukjupcx:/home/cvs/cvsroot</url>              
  </scm>**

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>  
  <plugins>   
  **<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>      
         <configuration>
            <scm:checkout>
            <scmVersion>correct</scmVersion>
            </scm:checkout>
         </configuration>
  </plugin>**
  </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- System dependencies -->
    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  <!-- External dependencies -->
    <!-- commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- commons-httpclient -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- commons-io -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- cryptix-jce-provider -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>cryptix-jce-provider</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- designJTC -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>designJTC</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dom4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- httpProxyPackage -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpProxyPackage</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jakarta-oro -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta-oro</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jaxen118 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxen118</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.8</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jms -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JMSInterfaceCreator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>JMSInterfaceCreator</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jxel_local -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxel_local</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.13</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- myCastor -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>myCastor</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- oscache -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tibjms -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uploadfile -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>uploadfile</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- xercesImpl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- xmlParserAPIs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- j2ee -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- rt 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vod.atom</groupId>
      <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

When i tried to run mvn scm:checout command I got following error

```
[swadmin@aukjupbx CIM_Transformation]$ mvn scm:checkout -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cim transformation
[INFO]    task-segment: [scm:checkout] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [scm:checkout {execution: default-cli}]
[ERROR] The connection string contains too few tokens.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cannot run checkout command :

Embedded error: Can't load the scm provider.
The scm url is invalid.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Cannot run checkout command :
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot run checkout command :
        at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.CheckoutMojo.checkout(CheckoutMojo.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.CheckoutMojo.execute(CheckoutMojo.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Can't load the scm provider.
        at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRepository(AbstractScmMojo.java:332)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.CheckoutMojo.checkout(CheckoutMojo.java:105)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.repository.ScmRepositoryException: The scm url is invalid.
        at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.cvslib.AbstractCvsScmProvider.makeProviderScmRepository(AbstractCvsScmProvider.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.makeScmRepository(AbstractScmManager.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRepository(AbstractScmMojo.java:273)
        ... 21 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 28 08:22:12 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/192M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you please tell me possible resolution.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the SCM url when using [CVS](http://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html) uses the following format when using the `pserver` method:

```
scm:cvs<delimiter>pserver<delimiter>[username[<delimiter>password]@]servername[<delimiter>port]<delimiter>path_to_repository<delimiter>module_name
```

Yours is missing the module name at the end (and is thus indeed invalid), your url should be something like (assuming `change1t` is the username):

```
scm:cvs:pserver:change1t@aukjupcx:/home/cvs/cvsroot:module_name
```

Comment: You are a machine, sir. Every question I click on, there you are. I salute you.

Comment: @warandpeace LOL :) I'm pretty active in some topics indeed.

Comment: @JoseK The joys of traveling.