# How to checkout code from CVS using Maven

Tags: java, maven, commit, cvs, vcs-checkout

I am looking for following things.

1. How to checkout code from CVS
2. How to checkin and update code from CVS

My CVS server name:**cecvs02dv** which can be accessed using user name and password **(and cannot be accessed over HTTP)**

CVS folder: c:\cvs\dev

Module name: i3LOC

Connection configuration to CVS

```
<scm>

<connection>scm:cvs:ext:cecvs02dv:c:\cvs\dev:i3LOC</connection>

</scm>
```

**Initial POM XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.td.insurance</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<scm>

<connection>scm:cvs:ext:cecvs02dv:c:\cvs\dev:i3LOC</connection>

</scm>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.td.insurance</groupId>
        <artifactId>batchframework</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
        <configuration>
           <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
           <goals>deploy</goals>
           <scmCommentPrefix>[bus-core-api-release-checkin]-</scmCommentPrefix>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <cvs>cvs_native</cvs>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.7:update (default-cli) on project Test: Cannot run update command : Ca
n't load the scm provider. The scm url is invalid. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any hint will be very useful

**Edited: After changing SCM tag in POM.xml**

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:cvs|pserver|username|password@cecvs02dv|c:/cvs/dev|IRM</connection>
 <developerConnection>scm:cvs|pserver|username|password@cecvs02dv|c:/cvs/dev|IRM</developerConnection>
<tag>HEAD</tag>
 <scm>
```

when I execute command **mvn scm:checkout**  it throws below error.

```
[INFO] Change the default 'cvs' provider implementation to 'cvs_native'.
[INFO] Removing D:\vinu\workspace\Maven\IRM\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "cvs -z3 -f -d     :pserver:username@cecvs02dv:c:/cvs/dev -q checkout -d checkout IRM"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\vinu\workspace\Maven\IRM\target
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The cvs command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Empty password used - try 'cvs login' with a real password
cvs [checkout aborted]: authorization failed: server cecvs02dv rejected access to     c:/cvs/dev for user username
```

However when I try to checkout using below command from command prompt it works

```
cvs -z3 -f -d :pserver:username:passsword@cecvs02dv:2401:c:\cvs\dev -q checkout -d checkout IRM
```

More details can be found here:

[How to checkout project from head using CVS command using windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600539/how-to-checkout-project-from-head-using-cvs-command-using-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: maybe the delimter used confuses the scm plugin: http://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html - the examples section on that page contains some variations better suited for windows (because of the : in the path)

Comment: Any idea on how to resolve this? I have tried several possible combinations with no success :(

Comment: It is pretty clear what is wrong **The scm url is invalid.** what it should be, no one but you can know because you know the names of the machines and path to what you want.

Comment: Have a look at the output when running Maven with `mvn -X -e ....`

Comment: @carlspring I'm still using Struts 1.x and Java 5/6

Comment: @ShotgunNinja: Wait, what year is this again...?

Comment: @Vinayak: If you could provide that output and also check with a CVS client, if you can connect to that URL, that could help figure it out...

Comment: @carlspring Where I work, it's like 2005.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson and carlspring: I can connect to URL: **pserver:vrdornala@cecvs02dv:c:\cvs\dev ** using eclipse CVS. I also used pserver instead of ext with same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception:invalid scm URL, on runing mvn scm:checkout command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040674/exceptioninvalid-scm-url-on-runing-mvn-scmcheckout-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend quite a some time and could not find a solution using Maven SCM plugin. Also the documentation for Maven SCM plugin is not that good.

I am able to resolve the issue using ant plugin (maven-antrun-plugin). For detail solution please refer

[CVS Checkout using MAVEN ANT plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146481/cvs-checkout-using-maven-ant-plugin/31173943#31173943)