# How to checkout project from head using CVS command using windows command prompt

Tags: cvs, windows-console, vcs-checkout

I searched extensively to resolve my issue, However could not find any solution.

**Requirement:** Need to checkout ADM project from HEAD.

**CVS server name**: cvs02dv (**CVS is installed on windows**)

**CVS server directory: c:\cvs\dev**  (The location were all the files can be accessed using eclipse or any CVS client tool like smartCVS)

**Project to be checked out from HEAD:** ADM

Using eclipse I can access the files using **pserver:user@cvs02dv:c:\cvs\dev**

I downloaded CVS client from below site, Unzipped in D:\vinu\installedSW\CVSClient directory.

http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/cvs-1-11-22.zip

**COMMAND USED TO CHECKOUT FROM WINDOW COMMAND LINE:**

```
D:\vinu\installedSW\CVSClient>cvs -d:pserver:usera@cvs02dv:c:\cvs\dev co ADM
```

**ERROR:**

```
cvs checkout: CVSROOT requires a path spec:
cvs checkout: :(gserver|kserver|pserver):[[user][:password]@]host[:[port]]/path
cvs checkout: [:(ext|server):][[user]@]host[:]/path
cvs [checkout aborted]: Bad CVSROOT: `:pserver:user@cvs02dv:c:\cvs\dev'.
```

**APPRECIATE ANY HINT**

Comment: Upvote for telling us in detail what you tried, what message you got, etc.

Comment: Try with  D:\vinu\installedSW\CVSClient>cvs -d:pserver:vrdornala@cecvs02dv:c:\\cvs\\dev co ADM   or with D:\vinu\installedSW\CVSClient>cvs -d:pserver:vrdornala@cecvs02dv:c:/cvs/dev co ADM

Comment: @JuanZe I tried this it does not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to resolve the issue, As I suspected the issue was due to CVS Client which I had used.

**Please do not use below CVS client as stated in my question**

http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/cvs-1-11-22.zip

**Instead download cvs client from below site**

http://www.cvsnt.org

1. Install CVS Client using above link, Say you installed in D:\CVSNT directory
2. Add D:\CVSNT in PATH variable, i.e Update PATH Environment variable with CVSNT path (right click on My Computer -->Advanced System settings --> Environment Variables -> Edit../New.. --> PATH)
3. Open command prompt to check whether cvs client is in path. Enter cvs -version

C:\test>**cvs -version**

```
Concurrent Versions System (CVSNT) 2.5.03 (Scorpio) Build 2151 (client/server)

Copyright (c) 1989-2001 Brian Berliner, david d `zoo' zuhn,
                    Jeff Polk, and other authors
CVSNT version (Nov 14 2005) Copyright (c) 1999-2005 Tony Hoyle and others
see http://www.cvsnt.org

Commercial support and training provided by March Hare Software Ltd.
see http://www.march-hare.com/cvspro

CVSNT may be copied only under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2,
a copy of which can be found with the CVS distribution.

The CVSNT Application API is licensed under the terms of the
GNU Library (or Lesser) General Public License.

SSH connectivity provided by PuTTY:
  PuTTY is copyright 1997-2001 Simon Tatham.
  Portions copyright Robert de Bath, Joris van Rantwijk, Delian
  Delchev, Andreas Schultz, Jeroen Massar, Wez Furlong, Nicolas Barry,
  Justin Bradford, and CORE SDI S.A.
  See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library (PCRE)
  Copyright (c) 1997-2004 University of Cambridge.
  Licensed under the BSD license.
  See http://www.pcre.org/license.txt

Specify the --help option for further information about CVS
```

4. Execute command:

**cvs -z3 -f -d :pserver:username:password@servername:2401:c:\cvs\dev -q checkout -d checkout IRM**